# How to get PyQt4 working with Spyder

Tags: python, pyqt4, spyder

I'm trying to step through some code using `Spyder (Python 3.6)` but I keep getting the below error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'

I have googled it and looked through Stack Overflow, but none of the possibilities seem to work.

Comment: It would be good if you could post some of the code you've already tried. We can go from there.

Comment: brew install pyqt

Comment: conda install pyqt=4

Comment: I get the error message "The Program can't start because QtCore4.dll is missing from your computer", when trying to install PYQT4 for Aneconda

Comment: I've downloaded Qtxml4.dll and that doesn't do much, does it have to be saved somewhere specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Qt4 is no longer supported in Anaconda, so no new packages were created for Python 3.6.

You could use a community channel called conda-forge to install PyQt4 for Python 3.6. However, that channel is not supported nor associated with Continuum (the company behind Anacoda).